# Exibir imagem armazenada no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysqli, longblob

Estou criando um cardápio digital que contém fotos dos pratos.
Armazenei a foto no BD MySQL utilizando o seguinte código:

Código HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="./processos/cadastra_item.php">
<p align="left">Imagem<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999"/>
    <input name="imagem" type="file"/>
</form>
```

Código PHP

```
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$tamanho = $_FILES['imagem']['size'];

if ( $imagem != "none" )
{
  $fp = fopen($imagem, "rb");
  $item->itemImg = fread($fp, $tamanho);
  $item->itemImg = addslashes($item->itemImg);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Após isso realizo o INSERT normalmente. O campo que armazena a imagem é do tipo LONGBLOB. Conferi pelo Workbench e a imagem foi armazenada com sucesso porém não consigo exibi-la na página.

O código que utilizei para tentar exibir a imagem segue abaixo:

```
echo "<center><img src='./processos/verImg.php?itemCod=\".$cod.\"' width='100' height='50' border='1'></center>"
```

PHP (Arquivo verImg.php)

```
$itemCod = $_GET['itemCod'];

    //Encontra o item no banco utilizando o código
    $sql = mysqli_query("SELECT itemCod, itemImg FROM Cardapio WHERE itemCod = ".$itemCod."");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_object($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //itemImg é o campo onde esta armazenada a imagem
    $bytes  = $row->itemImg;
    header( "Content-type: image/gif");              
    echo $bytes;
```

Tentei também utilizar `mysqli_fetch_array` mas não obtive sucesso em exibir a imagem.

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que quando eu abro a página, no lugar onde deveria aparecer a imagem apenas aparece um quadradinho vazio. Tentei com imagens JPG, PNG e JPEG.

Comment: Nesse trecho, `SELECT itemCod FROM`, onde está o campo da imagem? Não deveria ser `SELECT itemImg FROM`?

Comment: @DanielOmine realmente. Isso foi um erro ao transpor o código para o Stack. Já corrigi a pergunta. O erro está ocorrendo com o select feito da forma correta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser que o erro esteja no teu html para mostrar a imagem, você não tá especificando que é um base64. Tenta trocar a ultima linha para:

```
echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($bytes);
```

Comment: Antes do trecho `.base64_encode($bytes) .' ";` seria aspas duplas mesmo?

Comment: Tentei o que vc disse, e infelizmente não funcionou :/, será que o problema está na inclusão da imagem no banco de dados?

Comment: Comentei o header e a página me retornou alguns warnings que não entendi muito bem:

Warning: **mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante\processos\verImg.php on line 11**


Warning: **mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante\processos\verImg.php on line 13**


Notice: **Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurante\processos\verImg.php on line 14
data:image/jpeg;base64,'**

Comment: Corrigi o erro das aspas duplas. Se isso não resolve pode realmente ser a forma que você tá salvando a imagem. dá uma olhada nessa thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Comment: Utilizei a sua sugestão e as sugestões fornecidas no tópico **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql**. Funcionou corretamente.